# How to combine the texts and many images in same as a image using image manipulation in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Please guide me.I  don't know how to combine and create the thumbnail. Here is my unfinished code:

```
function createThumbnail() {
    $config['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $config['source_image'] = "uploads/" . 'blank.jpg';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = "800";
    $config['height'] = "800";
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {

        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    $con['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $con['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
    $con['source_image'] = 'uploads/' . '$adb.png';
    $con['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - John Doe';
    $con['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
    $con['wm_font_size'] = '16';
    $con['wm_font_color'] = 'A70000';
    $con['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $con['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
    $con['wm_padding_bottom'] = '10';


    $this->load->library('image_lib', $con);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($con);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();

    $this->load->view('upload_success');
}
```

I want to add texts and many images and create it as a single thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer by myself. Here is the code:

```
function createThumbnail() {
    $config['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $config['source_image'] = "uploads/" . 'index.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = "400";
    $config['height'] = "400";
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {

        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }


    $conf['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $conf['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
    $conf['source_image'] = 'uploads/' . 'blank.jpg';
    $conf['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $conf['wm_overlay_path'] = 'uploads/' . 'index_thumb.jpg';
    $conf['wm_opacity'] = '100';
    $conf['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'center';
    $conf['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
    $conf['wm_hor_offset'] = '10';
    $conf['wm_vrt_offset'] = '180';


    $this->load->library('image_lib', $conf);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($conf);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();

    $confi['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $confi['source_image'] = "uploads/" . 'blank_thumb.jpg';
    $conf['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $confi['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $confi['width'] = "1920";
    $confi['height'] = "1440";
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $confi);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($confi);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $con['image_library'] = "gd2";
    $con['wm_type'] = 'text';
    $con['source_image'] = 'uploads/' . 'blank_thumb_thumb.jpg';
    $con['wm_text'] = 'Project';
    $con['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
    $con['wm_font_size'] = '26';
    $con['wm_font_color'] = 'A70000';
    $con['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
    $con['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
    $con['wm_vrt_offset'] ='-300';
    $con['wm_hor_offset'] ='200';


    $this->load->library('image_lib', $con);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($con);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();

    $this->load->view('upload_success');
}
```